# Initiate a Draft.js Editor with unordered list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have an array of string that I want to pre-populate a draft.js editor with as an unordered list. 
Here's the code:

```
const content = ContentState.createFromText(input.join('*'), '*')
const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(content)
this.setState({ 
  editorState: RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, 'unordered-list-item'
})
```

This is only created a bullet point item for the first entry in the array but the other items are not inheriting the blockstyle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of [`ContentBlock`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-block.html#content)s with constructor `new ContentBlock()`. And generate initial editor state with [`ContentState.createFromBlockArray`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-block.html#content). Look at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/levsha/uy04se6r/

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const input = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

  const contentBlocksArray = input.map(word => {
    return new ContentBlock({
      key: genKey(),
      type: 'unordered-list-item',
      characterList: new List(Repeat(CharacterMetadata.create(), word.length)),
      text: word
    });
  });

  this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocksArray))
  };
}
```